# Is it bad practice to put booleans as method parameters?

Tags: oop

I did a code review with a junior developer and a discussion got brought up about Booleans which he read something in a book called 'Clean Code' by Robert Martin.  He said that the book explained that using booleans in parameters is bad practice and makes the code harder to test.  Specifically, we are talking about code similar to the below:

```
public static void setActivateValidation(Boolean activate)
{
    System.validation = activate;
    update System.validation;
}
```

and he is making the claim that is a very bad practice saying instead it should be 2 methods like:

```
public static void turnOffValidation()
{
    System.validation = false;
    update System.validation;
}

public static void turnOnValidation()
{
    System.validation = true;
    update System.validation;
}
```

Is there any reason the first example would be considered bad practice?  I personally dislike the second version since I feel like it's just duplicating code.  Unit tests would be very similar in both whereas I would need 2 tests either way.  I don't see how one is more complex than another to test.

Comment: Neither would surprise me, as long as the api was consistent. Do you have house rules for this sort of thing?

I would probably rename setActivateValidation to something like toggleValidation to make it clear when it does.

The bigger problem is where does System.validation come from. I hope you injected it in the constructor for the class!

Comment: If the method takes a single argument, I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior

Comment: In his book he says that methods with the least amount of arguments are the best bc arguments add complexity. That could be one reason. One more reason could be in languages like JS or Ruby there is potential error where someone sends in an arg that is not a boolean. The no args method wouldn't ever allow that.

Comment: A boolean parameter does not make things harder to test.

Comment: That was more my thinking.  Our house rules are typically that less methods would be better but it doesn't seem to fit directly into this specific case outside of the fact that he had these methods in 2 separate classes and I asked him to place them in a shared utility class.

Comment: @RobertMoskal It was a lazy loaded form of a global variable.  The Language/Framework we are using has special methods to get some data that are only allowed to be called so many times (governor limits in Salesforce).  We lazy loaded the values so that we don't have to make multiple calls to the same special methods using up extra calls to governor limits.  I adjusted it a little for simplicity purposes to try to take focus off of it but I must not have done well at that.

Comment: @Kai It's related and I saw that before I asked my question, but different from what I was asking.

Comment: @Taysky That situation could never happen in the language we are working in.

Comment: Isn't this just a trade off?  You'll then have a branch to decide on which function to invoke, which would need to be tested

Comment: @Kritner That's the question I asked.

Comment: @dphil in relation to the book Clean Code the language does not matter, his book applies to all of them. In regards to C, C++, Java etc, your right, that would not be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem in the first version of code. Just a setter with a simple logic.

IMHO, a situation where boolean as parameter is not good is when you use this parameter to branch logics inside the method. An easy example:

```
public void apply(boolean applyForAllUsers) {
    if (applyForAllUser) {
        // some logics to apply some operations for all users
    } else {
        // some logics to apply some operations for one users
    }
}
```

Bad things can happen to this method:

- Method will keep growing because it's doing more than one thing.
- Hard to understand depending on how each logic works.
- Hard to test.
- and a lot of other reasons.

In this case it makes more sense refactoring the code then the first version of your code.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the example I came up with when saying what I believed the author if the book was trying to say.

Comment: @dphil If something similiar happens next time, give him some facts based on your experience on this code review. Maybe doing this refactoring that your reviewer suggested was a good thing, or maybe not. But the next time you'll have facts and you'll have experienced this. So enjoy the experience. Doing wrong and getting right the next time is better than trying to get right in the first try. Good luck!